# Confusion with exterior algebra

Tags: exterior-algebra

I have a graded vector space $V$ such that $V=V^2\bigoplus V^3$, i.e $V^k=0\quad 
 \forall k\neq2,3.$

Now I can't understand what is $\bigwedge V^{\leq 2}$.

Is it $\bigwedge V^{\leq 2}=\bigwedge^0 V^{\leq 2}\bigoplus \bigwedge^1 V^{\leq 2}\bigoplus...$ with $V^{\leq 2}=V^2$?

Also what is $(\bigwedge V^{\leq 2})^2$?

Thanks!

Comment: Whatever it is, it's horrible notation. Where does this come from?

Comment: From the book Rational Homotopy Theory

Comment: I don't know that book ... does it have authors?

Comment: Felix-Halperin-Thomas

Comment: Can someone provide a pdf of the book Exterior algebras:elementary tribute to Grassman's ideas